# How to set cookie / use mechanize during carrierwave image downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to download some images. However some sites block access if cookies are not set properly. I want to use Mechanize in place to the open-uri calls so I can do some preparation and then download the image. Is it possible in Carrierwave?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this via your web server like nginx or Apache . If you want it more customizable and the conditions are closer to the rails app, you can do it in the routes.rb (Rack).

See a sample example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) and [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/)